# Querying number of children nodes for each node in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to come up with the best HiveQL query to get a list of rows where the one column would have the number of (direct) children that node has. the database is hierarchical so it looks like this:

```
| ID | Some other column | ParentID |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | NULL     |
| 2  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 1        |
| 3  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 2        |
| 4  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 1        |
```

And I am attempting to query it to output something like this:

```
| ID | Some other column | child count |
+--------------------------------------+
| 1  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 2           |
| 2  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 1           |
| 3  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 0           |
| 4  | XXXXXXXXXX x X X  | 0           |
```

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag? And do you really need assistance with such a basic SQL query?!?

Comment: sorry, the mysql tag was a mistake. This query does not seem basic to me but @SamsonScharfrichter if you do have a solution, can you please share it with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this with `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.id,
       COALESCE (b.child_count, 0) "child count"
FROM   mytable a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT parentid,
                         Count(*) child_count
                  FROM   mytable
                  GROUP  BY parentid) b
              ON a.id = b.parentid;
```

Comment: This worked only after I removed the brackets around the column name child count and changed it to child_count. Thank you Kaushik!